# Selecting a list of available numbers between a range, joining a reserved range table

Tags: sql, linq

I currently have three tables:

Product

```
    Number | Name | Description
```

ProductNumberReservation

```
    ID | Start | End | Description
```

NumberRange

```
    Num
```

NumberRange is simply a sequential list of possible product numbers (Effectively 1-999999).
ProductNumberReservation is a table that contains a range of Product numbers considered "Reserved"
Product is bog standard list of products in the system.

I want to be able to see the status of all product IDs in a range (example 1-6 below) something like so:

```
| Number | Description         |
|--------|---------------------|
| 1      | Our First Product   |
| 2      |                     |
| 3      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 4      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 5      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 6      |                     |
```

Reservations can overlap, but I'm happy with multiple rows being returned, like so:

```
| Number | Description         |
|--------|---------------------|
| 1      | Our First Product   |
| 2      |                     |
| 3      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 4      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 4      | Reservation Range 2 |
| 5      | Reservation Range 1 |
| 5      | Reservation Range 2 |
| 6      |                     |
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't understand why you need three tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need... (note that I've changed the field names Start and End to RangeStart and RangeEnd to avoid using the End keyword)

```
SELECT n.Num, COALESCE(p.Description, r.Description) as Description
FROM Numbers n
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
    ON n.Num = p.Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductNumberReservation r
    ON n.Num >= r.RangeStart
    AND n.Num <= r.RangeEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Although I did switch the join on range to be a between:
left outer join ProductNumberReservation r on n.Num between r.[Start] and r.[end]